# SQL Server count date

Tags: sql-server, date

I am new to sql and just learning queries.  I have a single table.  I need to count the rows based on the date that we have in the table called INSERTIONDATETIME (2013-10-15 17:11:44) so I can see how many studies were performed each month.  Each new study would be 1 row.  I want to be able to see how many studies we did each month, each year or however else I would need to see the data.

Comment: A proper question would include the table structure, example data and expected output.  In addition, the SQL query you tried and any errors or problems you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a lot more effort into asking a question, but this should get you going, The SQL [DATEPART](https://www.w3schools.com/Sql/func_datepart.asp) function extracts the month from the date field and then you can group by this value to give you a total each month. If you follow the link above to the info on `DATEPART` you will see that you can extract other date elements as required.

```
 SELECT DATEPART(month, YT.INSERTIONDATETIME) as StudyMonth, COUNT(*) FROM YOURTABLE YT 
 GROUP BY DATEPART(month, YT.INSERTIONDATETIME)
```

I would recommend some research online, which would reveal plenty of articles to go over SQL Query basics, here are a couple to get you going:

[TechNet Query Basics](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264565(v=sql.90).aspx)

[Simple SELECT Queries](https://www.essentialsql.com/getting-started-with-sql-server-simple-select-queries/)